# filtering request from IIS and redirecting it to Glassfish

Tags: iis, internet, glassfish

I have IIS running on my server on 80 i want if request with /webapplication comes then the request should be redirected to my glassfish from IIS it self glassfish is running on 8080

how to configure this., i want both of them running any how

Comment: without changing url..
i mean if user enters localhost.com/abc then it should be localhost.com/abc but the page should come from glassfish from port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I presume you set up a virtual directory called web application and then configure a filter to direct all requests on to Glassfish.  You'd use iis bindings to specify specific host headers/ports etc.  The exact steps vary depending on what version of IIS you're running.

Does this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4341/abdhq/index.html) help?